# Model::update() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using PHP and Laravel I try to update my model but I'm getting an error message :

```
message "Non-static method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::update() should not be called statically"
```

This is my code :

```
AttributeOption::update(array_merge([
                    'sort_order' => $sortOrder++,
                ], $optionInputs), $optionId);
```

Comment: `AttributeOption` is a Model, not a Facade. `AttributeOption::update()` is a static call to the `update()` method on the `AttributeOption` model. This method is not defined as a static method, so attempting to call it like one will throw the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `update()` wrong.

#### mass update with conditions:

```php
YourModel::where(/* some conditions */)
    ->update([
      'field1' => 'value1',
      'field2' => 'value2',
      ...
    ]);
```

#### mass update with no conditions

```php
YourModel::query()
    ->update([
      'field1' => 'value1',
      'field2' => 'value2',
      ...
    ]);
```

#### single model update

```php
$model = YourModel::where(/* some conditions */)->first();

$model->update([
  'field1' => 'value1',
  'field2' => 'value2',
  ...
]);

// Only accept fillable fields in the update

$model->fill([
  'field1' => 'value1',
  'field2' => 'value2',
  ...
])->save();

// Disregard fillable fields in the update

$model->forceFill([
  'field1' => 'value1',
  'field2' => 'value2',
  ...
])->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this too:

```
Model::find()
->update([
  'field1' => 'value1',
  'field2' => 'value2',
  ...
]);
```